# Store array data in single line PHP

Tags: php

Hello i want to store my array data into variable.

```
$array = array('0' => "14254",'1' => "145245");
// I want to store this array value into normal single variable
// store array data to $string.
// something like this >> $string is  14254,145245
```

Comment: if you want see  the real content  try use  var_dump($array)

Comment: i dont want to see this i want to store this

Comment: waht do you mean for store .? . (echo is not store)  how you build $script ?.. the code you showed  is not enough for a correct evaluation

Comment: i just show what output look like.i want store all array ids into variable for my another function

Comment: Sorry, but your question is extremely vague, it is unclear what you try to do. Obviously you can store into a variable whatever you want, you already do that. So what is the specific issue you are dealing with? Try not to ask _how_ you might be able to do something instead try to explain _what_ you actually try to do. And... there is an `edit` link below your question, please use it to revise your question. Do _not_ add details in comments. Thanks.

Comment: I want to store array data into a variable for example
i need only value remove > [0] , [2] < and only store data into variable not array as normal variable like this> 145214,1451245 < i need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array's `implode()` method.The `implode()` function returns a string from the elements of an array.

```
<?php

$array = array('0' => "14254",'1' => "145245");

$script = implode(',',$array);//outputs  14254,145245
echo $script;
?>
```

For more see manual [PHP Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Look at 'serialize' function in PHP. It will provide you array as a string that later could be converted back to array with 'unserialize'